# error: not assignable in macro function

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to write a function into a macro, but it is giving me a 'not assignable error'. My macro is this:

```
#define swapmacro(t, x, y) {t temp = x; x = y; y = temp;}
```

This is the code where I called it

```
int x = 4;
int y = 5;
swapmacro(int, 4, 5);
```

Then it gave me this error message:

```
stack.c:23:3: error: expression is not assignable
swapmacro(int, 4, 5);
^              ~
stack.c:7:43: note: expanded from macro 'swapmacro'
#define swapmacro(t, x, y) {t temp = x; x = y; y = temp;}
                                          ^
stack.c:23:3: error: expression is not assignable
swapmacro(int, 4, 5);
^                 ~
stack.c:7:50: note: expanded from macro 'swapmacro'
#define swapmacro(t, x, y) {t temp = x; x = y; y = temp;}
                                                 ^
```

Comment: you mean swapmacro(int, x,y)

Comment: May I recommend leaving macros for rare edge cases and using a function? Odds are really good that the optimizer will inline it or strip it of a s much calling overhead as possible? One reason: functions are easily inspected with a debugger. Macros, not so much.

Comment: or even be a standard http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/

Answer (score 3):

```
swapmacro(int, 4, 5);
```

expands to this:

```
{int temp = 4; 4 = 5; 5 = temp;};
```

Neither `4 = 5` nor `5 = temp` are valid expressions. Integer literals cannot be lvalues. Perhaps you meant to do this:

```
swapmacro(int, x, y);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not resort to something that uses a macros?

See [swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

So the code could be

```
std::swap(x,y);
```

with type safety etc.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think it would necessarily make the program more efficient. I was just wondering about macros.